# How to check timer ticks how many times?

Tags: wpf, timer

I have a timer which ticks once every second. I would like to check when it ticks 60 times which means a minute and have it do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming C#, this should do the job:

```
private int m_Time = 0;

private void Timer_Tick(...)
{
    m_Time++;
    if (m_Time == 60)
    {
        m_Time = 0;
        // it's been 60 seconds, do whatever
    }
    // do your "every 1 second" code here
}
```

Essentially you make a private field that counts the number of seconds that have ticked by, then check if it's 60. If it is, a minute has passed and you can perform your logic. Then set the counter back to 0 and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Create an int field, increment it every tick, and in an `if(field == 60)` block you can do "something".